# PayPal IPN custom field cannot get variable from drop down list

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, paypal, paypal-ipn

All I want to accomplish is to allow the user to select their username from the drop down list and choose their item they want to purchase using that account. One problem is that when the PayPal button is clicked, the username is not stored in the custom field but the transaction goes through well.

PayPal button code:

```
    // Get information from database
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM account WHERE mainusername='".$username."'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<option>".$row['username']."</option>";

}
?>
</select>
</tr>
</td>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="itemforsale">
<select name="os0">
    <option value="shirt">shirt $5.55 USD</option>
    <option value="short">short $31.55 USD</option>
    <option value="skirt">skirt $62.75 USD</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['getusername'])) {

$getusername = $_POST['getusername']; 
echo "".$getusername."";

}
?>
">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgetting to set the "option" value when iterating through usernames. It should look like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM account WHERE mainusername='".$username."'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo "<option value='".$row['username']."'>".$row['username']."</option>";
}
```

I also recommend using jQuery for this. The page wouldn't have to reload.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $("#username_select").change(function() { 
                $("#paypal_custom").val($(this).val());
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Set the username  ID to "username_select" and the Paypal "custom" hidden input ID to "paypal_custom".

Comment: @LionelSanchez I updated the code for first one, but second one should be in your <head> right after you include jquery.

Comment: @LionelSanchez which method did you use?

Comment: Managed to insert the javascript but I'm not that sure what do you mean by "Set the username ID to "username_select" and the Paypal "custom" hidden input ID to "paypal_custom"."

Comment: Which part should I change to username_select? @Raphael Caixeta

Comment: Is it possible to automatically get the first item from the drop down list to the input on page load? @Raphael-Caixeta